# validation is not working after setting scenario

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

my client side validation is not working after creating scenarios. it works fine before creating scenario . i have two scenarios update and create, i've two field to be required on *create scenario* and i've one field to be required on *update scenario*
**my model**

```
        class BaseBroadcast extends BaseActiveRecord
    {
      const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';
      const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';


/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [
            [
                'freight_charges_unit',
                'requested_response_date',
                'close_reason'
            ],
            'required'
        ],
       ......
    ];
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function scenarios(): array
{
    parent::scenarios();
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['close_reason'],
        self::SCENARIO_CREATE => ['freight_charges_unit','requested_response_date']

    ];
}
```

}

and i used create scenario like

```
$model = new Broadcast();
$model->scenario = Broadcast::SCENARIO_CREATE;
```

this 
and update scenario like

```
$model = Broadcast::findOne(['id' => $id]);
$model->scenario = Broadcast::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
```

this.

i'm enabled client side validation on my forms

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ......,
    'enableClientValidation' => true,]) ?>
```

Comment: So what is happening? These fields are not validated as required anymore with scenarios?

Comment: yes. when i click on submit with required field as empty the form is submitting

Comment: You don't have to set `'enableClientValidation' => true` - this is default and this line `parent::scenarios();` does nothing. Anyway could you show the code of controller's action that operates on this model?

Comment: **update scenario action**


`public function actionClose($id)
    {
        $model = Broadcast::findOne(['id' => $id]);
        $model->status = Broadcast::STATUS_CLOSED;
        $model->scenario = Broadcast::SCENARIO_UPDATE;
        if ($model->load(post()) && $model->update(true, ['close_reason', 'status'])) {
            \setFlash('success', Yii::t('company', 'Broadcast Closed Successfully!!!'));
            return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
        }
        return $this->render('_closeReasonForm', ['model' => $model]);
    }`

Comment: Not sure what `post()` is but it looks ok. Can you show `_closeReasonForm` as well? Update question with it, it's hard to read code without formatting.

Comment: try to call rules function after scenarion function call, and use , 'on' => 'update' after your validation rule

Answer (score 0):

Try this order on model

```
const SCENARIO_UPDATE = 'update';
const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';


public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_UPDATE => ['close_reason'],
        self::SCENARIO_CREATE => ['freight_charges_unit','requested_response_date']
    ];
}

public function rules()
{
  return [
            [['freight_charges_unit','requested_response_date'], 'required','on' => 'create'],
            [['close_reason'], 'required','on' => 'update'],
    ];
}
```

And this in controller

> $model = new Broadcast(['scenario' => 'create']);
>
> //for update
>
> $model = $this->findModel($id);
>
> $model->scenario = 'update';